# PHP - upload APK to own server

Tags: php, forms, apk-expansion-files

i'm trying to upload APK file to my own server with below codes. it work correctly sometimes with some apk files , but i can't upload some apk file , for example i can upload a file that name is "test" and size is 1.5 mb , but another file name "test2" and size 3.5  not uploading .

**PHP :**

```
function updateAPK($id){

   $name = $id.".apk";
   $temp = $_FILES["application"]["tmp_name"];
   $extension = array("application/octet-stream","application/vnd.android.package-archive");
   $DIR = __DIR__."\\..\\android\\{$id}\\";

    // apk format validation
    if(in_array($_FILES["application"]["type"],$extension )){

        //create directory if not exist
        if(!dirExist($DIR)){
            createDir($DIR);
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($temp,$DIR."\\{$name}")){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["upload"])){
   updateAPK($id);
}
?>

<form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="application">select APK :</label>
<input type="file" name="application" id="application" class="form-control" required/>
<div align="center">
<button type="submit" name="upload" value="upload" class="btn btn-default">upload</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you looked into upload limits of apache?

Comment: Could you include the apache (or whatever http server you're using) log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server settings are preventing uploads of big files. Please run the following script and post results:

```
<?php
echo "post_max: " . ini_get('post_max_size') . "<br>";
echo "upload_max_filesize: " . ini_get('upload_max_filesize')  . "<br>";
echo "Trying to set values<br>";
ini_set('post_max_size','16M';)
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','16M';)
echo "post_max: " . ini_get('post_max_size','16M');
echo "upload_max_filesize: " . ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
?>
```

The lower of the 2 values is the upper limit of what you can upload. Eventually they can be changed using phps ini_set